# Meaning of 「のでは」

Tags: grammar

What does のでは mean in the following sentence?  What changes if we write this sentence like this - デカイ腹に集中した、というのが?

> こいつは大らかというか・・・・・・いつも寝てばかりいる印象がある。ってかいつも寝てる。寝過ぎで余った栄養が全部そのデカイ腹に集中した**のでは**、というのが、クラスに於ける男子たちの共通見解だ。

*All of the excessive nutritions appeared because of the oversleeping, are gathering in his stomach, it's the opinion of boys in our class.*

---

I think the meaning is different from the sentence below.

> 夏中エアコンのきいた室内にいた**のでは**、日焼けするはずがない。

*You can't get a tan by staying in an air-conditioned room through summer.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [「研究社　新和英中辞典」](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF)：

> ‐では
>
> 1 〈…においては〉 in; at; to; as for; in the case of
>
> 2 〈…から判断すると〉 judging by [from]; from.
>
> 3 〈…に関しては〉
>
> 4 〈…であっては, …であったら〉
>
> 5 〈…ではないだろうか〉

「全部そのデカイ腹に集中したのでは」 seems to be an instance of 5, i.e. an abbreviation of 「ではないだろうか」, while 「夏中エアコンのきいた室内にいたのでは」an instance of 4.

By removing 「のでは」 you reduce a rhetorical question to a plain statement.