# のでは at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar

> やはりやめたほうがよい**のでは**

I have this sentence, and i wonder, is it the same as じゃないか?

Like やはりやめたほうがいい**じゃないか**？

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17658/45489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you are correct.
This sentence is just omitting 「ないか」after the 「のでは」. It just sounds slightly nicer to word it this way.